# Multiple simultaneous ajax request returns 504 Gateway Timeout

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, nginx, promise

When my web application runs multiple ajax request at the same time, I am getting a 504 Gateway Timeout. It starts when I have 5 simultaneous ajax requests, no matter simple the query is (Even a simple select gender_code from gender that returns 2 records only or such as long as the request more than 5).

I'm using deferred and promises like so:

```
var ajaxRequest = function(path) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: path,
        dataType: 'json',
    })
}


var getAjaxRequest = function(path) {
    var promise = $.Deferred();

    $.when(ajaxRequest(path)).done(function(data, status, jqXHR) {
        promise.resolve(data);
    });

    return promise.promise();
}

var main = getAjaxRequest('main');

var a1 = getAjaxRequest('path1');
var a2 = getAjaxRequest('path2');
var a3 = getAjaxRequest('path3');
var a4 = getAjaxRequest('path4');
var a5 = getAjaxRequest('path5');

// execute main first
$.when(main).done(function(data) {
    // execute remaining when main has finish loaded
    $.when(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5).done(function() {
        // when all are done, display everything at once.
    });
});
```

Using homestead running on vagrant while my web app is Laravel 5.6

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with your code*. It looks like your server is limiting concurrent connections, check the config. * = Although making 5 simultaneous requests is never a good idea. Try to merge the data in to a single request instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Rory. Though in terms of performance, which would be faster, 5 simultaneous request or a single request that will return all results? This is because the web app connects to an API. So having 5 request means making 5 web app request to 5 API endpoints while 1 single request makes 5 API endpoint request in 1 web app request.

Comment: That depends on the work being done in the request and how many concurrent users you have, but in general terms, 1 larger request is much better than 5 smaller ones. The latter will not scale at all.